# evaluating an integral with complex exponential (spectral density)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory

I am having a hard time figuring out how to evaluate this integral from a book that I am reading.

Here's the background info but I doubt it's highly relevant to the problem at hand:
$X$ is a real valued, weakly stationary random field defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with mean 0, variance 1, and correlation function

$r(\tau)=\exp{(-\frac{1}{2}(\tau_1^2+2\rho\tau_1\tau_2+\tau_2^2))},\,\,\tau \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

The spectral density $s(v) $can be computed as

$s(v)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\tau\cdot v}r(\tau)\,d\tau_1\,d\tau_2$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Any help on how to evaluate the integral above?

Here are the things that bother me:
The complex exponential. On the one hand, I can split it into the sine and cosine but $r(\tau)$ has the term $\tau_1 \tau_2$ which makes it hard to separate the variables. Should I introduce a transformation or change of variables?

The answer I should obtain is $s(v)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp{(-\frac{v_1^2-2\rho v_1 v_2 + v_2^2}{2(1-\rho^2)})}$ which is clearly the density of a normally distributed random vector in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Help very much appreciated.

EDIT: After following Robert's useful comment, I found a suitable transformation to break down the product. Now, I'm left to evaluate this integral and this is where I'm stumped:

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{\left(-i\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+p}})(v_1+v_2)-\frac{1}{4}x^2 \right)}\,dx$.

I am not sure if separating the complex exponential into its real and imaginary parts is the way to go since that will result in an integral of the form $\cos(x)e^{-x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start by diagonalizing the quadratic form $\tau_1^2 + 2 \rho \tau_1 \tau_2 + \tau_2^2$.

EDIT
Further hint:  $V(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp( x t - x^2/4)\; dx$ for real $t$ can be done by "completing the square".  But the formula is exactly the same for complex $t$, since $V(t)$ is an entire function of $t$.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by diagonalize?

Comment: sorry I now get what you mean after googling about what you said

Comment: so $\tau_1 ^2 + 2\rho \tau_1 \tau_2 + \tau_2^2 = e^TKe$ where $e = [\tau_1 \tau_2]$ and $K$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix with 1 on the diagonals and $\rho$ on the off diagonals. but where do i go from this? This is unfamiliar territory for me...

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm s}\pars{v}={1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
     \exp\pars{-\ic\tau\cdot v}
     \exp\pars{-\,{\tau_{1}^{2} + 2\rho\tau_{1}\tau_{2} + \tau_{2}^{2} \over 2}}
     \,d\tau_{1}\,d\tau_{2}: {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\rm s}\pars{v}&={1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\ic\tau\cdot v} \exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{%
> \tau_{2} + \rho\tau_{1}}^{2} + \bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}\tau_{1}^{2} \over 2}}
> \,d\tau_{1}\,d\tau_{2}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\!
> \exp\pars{-\ic\bracks{\tau_{1}v_{1} + \pars{\tau_{2} - \rho\tau_{1}}v_{2}}}\times
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}
> \exp\pars{-\,{\tau_{2}^{2} + \bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}\tau_{1}^{2} \over 2}}
> \,d\tau_{1}\,d\tau_{2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}\braces{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\,\half\,\pars{1 - \rho^{2}}\tau_{1}^{2}-\ic\bracks{v_{1} - \rho v_{2}}\tau_{1}}
> \,\dd\tau_{1}}\times
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{={1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}}\braces{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,\half\,\tau_{2}^{2} - \ic v_{2}\tau_{2}}\,\dd\tau_{2}}
> \end{align}

$$
\mbox{Use}\qquad
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-ax^{2} + \ic bx}
=\root{\pi \over a}\exp\pars{-\,{b^{2} \over 4a}}\,,\quad\Re\pars{a} > 0
$$

> \begin{align}
> {\rm s}\pars{v}&={1 \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}\,
> \root{2\pi \over 1 - \rho^{2}}\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{v_{1} - \rho v_{2}}^{2} \over 4\bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}/2}}
> \root{2\pi}\exp\pars{-v_{2}^{2} \over 4/2}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2\pi\root{1 - \rho^{2}}}
> \exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{v_{1} - \rho v_{2}}^{2}
> +\bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}v_{2}^{2}\over 2\bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
{\rm s}\pars{v}={1 \over 2\pi\root{1 - \rho^{2}}}
\exp\pars{-\,{v_{1}^{2} - 2\rho v_{1}v_{2} + v_{2}^{2} \over 2\bracks{1 - \rho^{2}}}}}\,,\quad
\Re\pars{\rho^{2}} < 1
$$